# Passing variable to php file that generates random link

Tags: php, variables, include

How can I pass variable(s) to randomlink.php, I tried adding it to randomlink.php as randomlink.php?stockid=$stockid , but this does not seem to work.

```
echo "<a href='";
include('randomlink.php');
echo "'>" . $item['stockid'] . "</a>";
```

Comment: first GET variable bust start with `?` then all other variables are with `&`

Comment: The variabel itself is already there, if I do a simple echo it displays, but when I use it in the url list the variable is not working, simply displaying $color as a word/text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue using a global variable

```
global $stockid2;    
    $stockid2 = $item['stockid'];
```